# Returning two Scala futures when both end

Tags: scala

The `method1` below is an attempt to return the results of two Future methods `someFutureMethod1` and `someFutureMethod2` combined. Any ideas how to make this work? Ideally the method that ends first should wait until the second ends, and then return the future values combined.

```
  def method1 ( s: Seq[Int]): Future [(Int,Int)] = {
      s.map { sx =>
          val future = someFutureMethod1 (sx)
          future.map {
            result => result
          }
          val future2 = someFutureMethod2 (sx)
          future2.map {
            result2 => result2
          }
          (result,result2)  // <-- the method should return the two results in the future
       }
  }


def someFutureMethod1 (i: Int) = Future { 
    i + 1
  }

def someFutureMethod2 (i: Int) = Future { 
    i + 2
  }
```

Comment: It's very easy to combine the futures with zip: `future.zip(future2)`. but you also map on a Seq. So it looks like you should return a Seq of such Future's, right?

Comment: No, it should return a pair of Ints

Comment: But map on Seq returns another Seq. Then how do you want the Future's to be combined to return just one Future?

Comment: my bad, you should return a Seq

Comment: Then see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You combine Future's in a map, so it looks like you have to return a Seq of such Future's:

```
def method1 ( s: Seq[Int]): Seq[Future [(Int,Int)]] =
  s.map { sx =>
    val future = someFutureMethod1 (sx)
    val future2 = someFutureMethod2 (sx)
    future.zip(future2)
  }
```

Comment: Using ```Future.sequence``` in addition to ```future.zip``` would result in a method with signature ```Future[Seq[(Int, Int)]]```. That would be easier to use in most cases.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Actually, the author asked how to do it, but then removed the comment. So I assumed they had figured it out themselves.